# Regex issue on SQL

Tags: mysql, regex

Why do I get 0 when running this expression?

```
SELECT 'Nr. 1700-902-8423. asdasdasd' REGEXP '1+[ ,.-/\]*7+[ ,.-/\]*0+[ ,.-/\]*0+[ ,.-/\]*9+[ ,.-/\]*0+[ ,.-/\]*2+[ ,.-/\]*8+[ ,.-/\]*4+[ ,.-/\]*2+[ ,.-/\]*3+';
```

I need to get true, when the text contains the specified number (`17009028423`). There can be symbols `,.-/\` between digits.
For example, if I have number 17009028423, I need get true when in text is:

- 1700-902-8423
- 17-00,902-84.23
- 170/09-0.28\423
- 1700..902  842-3
- 17,.009028 4//2\3
- etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your regular expression. First is that backslash in `\]` escapes the special meaning of `]` to denote a character class. You need to escape your backslash: `\\]`. Another problem is that `-` denotes a *range* `[` and `]` (e.g. `[a-zA-Z]`). You need to escape that too or put it at the end like `[a-zA-Z-]` (as @tenub said). Plus the backslashes should be escaped themselves, which makes:

```
SELECT 'Nr. 1700-902-8423. asdasdasd' REGEXP '1[ ,./\\\\-]*7[ ,./\\\\-]*0[ ,./\\\\-]*0[ ,./\\\\-]*9[ ,./\\\\-]*0[ ,./\\\\-]*2[ ,./\\\\-]*8[ ,./\\\\-]*4[ ,./\\\\-]*2[ ,./\\\\-]*3'
```

You can [check for yourself](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29181/0). 
I also removed `+` signs in case you want to match each number only once.

Comment: No need to escape `-`. Just put it at the end inside the `[]`. ;)

Comment: We could really confuse things and use the range `[,-/]` for `[,./-]`